# The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server. MacOS Sierra

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

- I installed and configured phpmyadmin on my machine. The phpmyadmin folder's path is `~/Sites/phpmyadmin` and my project is in `~/Sites/Meetings`.
- The path in the `httpd.conf` file for DocumentRoot is the project's path (`~Sites/Meetings`)

When I visit localhost on my browser, the complete directory of the project is visible with no issues. However, when I visit `localhost/phpmyadmin`, I get an error:

> Not Found The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.

Is there something wrong with the configuration, the folder's path or what...?

I just recently started working with PHP, MySql, and PHPMyAdmin, so guidance is highly needed.

**OS: Mac OSx High Sierra 10.13.3
PHP 7.1.7
MySQL 8.0.11
PHPMyAdmin 4.8.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

Because your DocumentRoot is set to ~Sites/Meetings and phpmyadmin is installed on the same level under ~/Sites/ so it couldn't find it...
The easy way is probably to set your `DocumentRoot` to `~/Sites/`

then you can reach:

```
http://localhost/Meetings
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

On real environment to external you need to be careful on what files you are exposing under Sites/
The other option would be to move phpmyadmin under `~/Sites/Meetings` and keep your current config.

Comment: Your suggested solution works. 
However, for the production environment, is it a correct practice to have the phpmyadmin folder in the project's folder?

Comment: No, I will not recommend that.  You should configure these in separate directories.  Personally I would setup VirtualHost.

[https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html]


Also, you should move Sites out of your personal home directory.